# Disabled a <td> in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to disable value entry in a <td> in my table.
Here is the affected line in my development:
`<td contenteditable id="data12"></td>`

Thanks in advance!

I've been browsing the Stack Overflow discussion topics and have seen this solution several times:
`$('#data12').prop("disabled",true);`
But it doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at [the docs for contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)

Comment: Would you please add a code example? JSFiddle or CodeSandbox?

Comment: remove `contenteditable` , it will make it non editable.

Comment: I found what I wanted. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution !

```
$('#data12').attr('contenteditable','false');
```